# Error 1064(42000) sql generado workbench

Tags: sql, mariadb

Me sale este error al importar el sql al phpmyadmin. He mirado varios posts y he visto que si quito VISIBLE pues debería de funcionar y nada. No se aun programar sql por tanto no entiendo muy bien el error. Os dejo el error a continuacion:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 121: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')
> ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 2
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 1

Os dejo aqui el codigo que se me ha generado:

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Thu Jan 28 19:57:32 2021
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`concierto`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`concierto` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `fecha` DATETIME NULL,
  `duracion` TIME NULL,
  `temporada` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `titulo` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`interprete`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`interprete` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `curriculum` VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
  `tipo` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`pieza`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`pieza` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `titulo` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `autor` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`grupo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`grupo` (
  `formacion` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `interprete_id` INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_grupo_interprete1_idx` (`interprete_id` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`interprete_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_grupo_interprete1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`interprete_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`interprete` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`individual`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`individual` (
  `instrumento` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `interprete_id` INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_individual_interprete1_idx` (`interprete_id` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`interprete_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_individual_interprete1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`interprete_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`interprete` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`orquesta`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`orquesta` (
  `num_musico` INT NULL,
  `director` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `interprete_id` INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_orquesta_interprete1_idx` (`interprete_id` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`interprete_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_orquesta_interprete1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`interprete_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`interprete` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`entradas`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`entradas` (
  `fila` INT NOT NULL,
  `asiento` INT NOT NULL,
  `fecha` DATETIME NULL,
  `hora` TIME NULL,
  `precio` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fila`, `asiento`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`table8`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`table8` (
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`tocar`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tocar` (
  `pieza_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `interprete_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pieza_id`, `interprete_id`),
  INDEX `fk_pieza_has_interprete_interprete1_idx` (`interprete_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_pieza_has_interprete_pieza1_idx` (`pieza_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pieza_has_interprete_pieza1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pieza_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`pieza` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pieza_has_interprete_interprete1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`interprete_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`interprete` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`vender`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`vender` (
  `entradas_fila` INT NOT NULL,
  `entradas_asiento` INT NOT NULL,
  `concierto_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entradas_fila`, `entradas_asiento`, `concierto_id`),
  INDEX `fk_entradas_has_concierto_concierto1_idx` (`concierto_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_entradas_has_concierto_entradas1_idx` (`entradas_fila` ASC, `entradas_asiento` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_entradas_has_concierto_entradas1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`entradas_fila` , `entradas_asiento`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`entradas` (`fila` , `asiento`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_entradas_has_concierto_concierto1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`concierto_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`concierto` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`tocar`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tocar` (
  `pieza_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `interprete_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pieza_id`, `interprete_id`),
  INDEX `fk_pieza_has_interprete_interprete1_idx` (`interprete_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_pieza_has_interprete_pieza1_idx` (`pieza_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pieza_has_interprete_pieza1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pieza_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`pieza` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pieza_has_interprete_interprete1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`interprete_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`interprete` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`participar`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`participar` (
  `individual_interprete_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `grupo_interprete_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`individual_interprete_id`, `grupo_interprete_id`),
  INDEX `fk_individual_has_grupo_grupo1_idx` (`grupo_interprete_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_individual_has_grupo_individual1_idx` (`individual_interprete_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_individual_has_grupo_individual1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`individual_interprete_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`individual` (`interprete_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_individual_has_grupo_grupo1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`grupo_interprete_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`grupo` (`interprete_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`participar`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`participar` (
  `individual_interprete_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `grupo_interprete_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`individual_interprete_id`, `grupo_interprete_id`),
  INDEX `fk_individual_has_grupo_grupo1_idx` (`grupo_interprete_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_individual_has_grupo_individual1_idx` (`individual_interprete_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_individual_has_grupo_individual1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`individual_interprete_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`individual` (`interprete_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_individual_has_grupo_grupo1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`grupo_interprete_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`grupo` (`interprete_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Pues eso, tienes un syntax error (error de sintaxis) alrededor del fragmento de código SQL que dice `') ENGINE = InnoDB`. Revisa, está mal escrita tu sentencia. Tampoco se entiende cuál era el `VISIBLE` que quitaste porque no está en el código que compartes.

Comment: El problema es que aun no he tocado sql, estoy estudiando modelo relacional y no encuentro el fallo aun.

Comment: Hora de aprender en la práctica :) Así comenzamos todos

Answer (score 2):

Tienes una tabla

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`table8`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`table8` (
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

¿No será que esto no va? No te fíes de lo autogenerado y haz debug ejecutando los SQL por secciones para validar cuál falla